# SQL add sub-index column on query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an SQL table in the following approximate format

```
+----+------------+------------+----------+------+
| id |  fin_date  | student_id | course_id| mark |
+----+------------+------------+----------+------+
|  1 | 2018-05-03 |      10049 |        1 |  60  |
|  2 | 2018-05-03 |      10032 |        2 |  45  |
|  3 | 2018-05-03 |      10032 |        1 |  88  |
|  4 | 2018-05-03 |      10032 |        1 |  96  |
+----+------------+------------+----------+------+
```

Unfortunately, I have just been asked to then have an index for a "student_course_id" sub-index that represents the number of courses that student had taken up until that time... Example below

```
+----+------------+------------+----------+------+-------------------+
| id |  fin_date  | student_id | course_id| mark | student_course_id |
+----+------------+------------+----------+------+-------------------+
|  1 | 2018-05-03 |      10049 |        1 |  60  |   1               |
|  2 | 2018-05-03 |      10032 |        2 |  45  |   1               |
|  3 | 2018-05-03 |      10032 |        3 |  88  |   2               |
|  4 | 2018-05-03 |      10032 |        4 |  96  |   3               |
|  5 | 2018-05-03 |      10049 |        2 |  60  |   2               |
+----+------------+------------+----------+------+-------------------+
```

This way when you lookup index id=3 between two dates, you then can immediately tell that its the 2nd course that student has taken.

I don't really want to add a new column to my table, is there any way to add this extra column in a similar way to COUNT(*) can be used to total unique fields in a single column?

Comment: If you're up to using an HTML table, you could use (an) alias(es) and then format them into it, set inside a loop. I know there's a way to do it in sql but I can't remember how it's done. The darn thing's on the tip of my tongue too. Edit: Here we go, I just remembered (10 secs. later). It's called a PIVOT (table) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table. I think that can be used for this here.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned above, this is an SQL table, everything being processed server side, but I am not grabbing the entire table when querying for a student, Hmm... I'll update the question with a little more information.

Comment: ok I think I get the gist here. You can count specific columns while using aliases if needed, and running through this a SELECT with a GROUP BY and/or DISTINCT if you're looking for unique fields. The alias for the new column you want, would be used for it.

Comment: I actually managed to get it working using a subquery, thank you for taking time to try to help me :)

Comment: Sure thing, *cheers*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I guess I asked a little prematurely. I figured it out...

```
SELECT *, ( select count(*) from `marks` t2 
where t1.student_id = t2.student_id and t1.id >= t2.id ) 
as student_course_id FROM `marks` as t1
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, but did you already have some form of query  that you tried but didn't work the way you wanted it to?

Comment: The query I need to run is very similar to above, but I would also be limiting by date range or something in the outer query, but this should work

Comment: ok. Yet... about your *"but this should work"* - It should or it does? Two different animals here ;-)

Comment: I will know soon, I am putting it all into the report queries now(They generate a series of pdfs server side) the cron job will run in about 40 min here. It works for the queries I have tested with through phpmyadmin

Comment: Your correlated subquery solution looks fine to me. You can also use an uncorrelated subquery or @variables to build a rolling total. These methods are worth investigating if performance becomes an issue, but I see no reason not to 'accept' your own answer